# How to remove a section of .ai layered file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I have a layered Illustrator file of a world map. Each layered holding various info such as, country name layer, capital city layer, lake name layer etc. I would like to cut out, for example, a rectangular shape containing North America. I want to then save this area only but preserve the layers for editing. Can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "cut out"?  Are you looking to select a specific section of the map?

Comment: Please attach the snapshot with visual representation

Comment: ErickP. Hi, yes. Cut out a rectangular section and have that section as a separate .ai file that can has its layers reserved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is probably to first duplicate your file, so you're working with a copy. Next, in the new document, make sure all layers are unlocked, then Select All (Cmd-A or Ctrl-A). This will select everything in your document.

Then, while holding down the CMD key (CTRL key on a PC), click on each of the items you want to keep (Everything relating to North America). When that's done, hit "Delete". Everything you don't want will be deleted, and everything you want to keep will remain, on their original layers.

Good luck!

EDIT: (Was too long to add as a comment below)
In answer to your comment, using a rectangle (by dragging your mouse) would probably select/deselect more items than you'd like. So another option would be to follow the steps in the first paragraph above, then using the Lasso Tool while hold down the Option (Alt) key to surround the items you want to keep. Holding the Option (Alt) key will put a little "minus sign" on the tool's cursor, meaning it's going to subtract/deselect all points you surround. Once you do this, you can hit "Delete", and you should be left with everything you want to keep.

This isn't a foolproof method, as sometimes certain areas/points will be selected when you don't want them to be, so you'll have to be careful (and again, do this on a COPY of your original file). But it's probably the best method for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I guess I could do that, however there are 1000's of things I would need to select. Is there a quicker way to select everything within a rectangle for example?

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Thank you so very much!! Perfect!!! Greatly appreciate your time and advice!!